# Unequally spaced txt file into dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a .txt file which looks like this:

```
College Names Food rating Critic Rating Student rating

John Hopkins Institute 8.4 8.6 9.2

Stanford : New School 9.4 5.6 9.2

Mayor College 6.4 7.6 4.2
```

.
.
.
**These are all *space* separated values in a txt file.**

I want to import this data in the above format in R studio in the following table format: (There are much more rows than this)

| College Names | Food rating | Critic Rating | Student rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Hopkins Institute | 8.4 | 8.6 | 9.2 |
| Stanford : New School | 9.4 | 5.6 | 9.2 |
| Mayor College | 6.4 | 7.6 | 4.2 |

I think it can be done taking that only the first column contains characters and after this there are only numbers. Headers can be added later.

But the issue is that they aren't evenly spaced. John Hopkins Institute has 3 spaces while Mayor College has only 2 spaces, so cannot import it as data.table.

Comment: `read.csv(text = gsub(' (?=\\d)', ',', readLines('data.txt')[-1], perl = TRUE), header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::extract` with a custom regular expression:

```
d <- tibble(input=c("John Hopkins Institute 8.4 8.6 9.2",
"Stanford : New School 9.4 5.6 9.2",
"Mayor College 6.4 7.6 4.2"))

result <- d %>% extract(input,
          regex="(.+) ([.\\d]+) ([.\\d]+) ([.\\d]+)",
          into=c("College Names", "Food rating", "Critic Rating", "Student rating"))
```

Convert the result to a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(result)
```

See the explanation of the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/fmQiU7/1

Comment: You were a few split seconds earlier.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann and I provided a RexEx101 link

Comment: I tried this. But this returns a tibble and when I convert it into a dataframe using as.data.frame(d), it just makes the same txt file (3 rows and again 1 column). Is there a way to make it into a dataframe ?

Comment: you need to assign the result from the second line to a variable. I add the appropriate line. but the conversion to data.frame should not be necessary. a tibble is equivalent/compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look to find a suitable way to read-in the file in a way you can process it. If that fails, here's an answer to structure the data after reading-in:

Read-in:

```
df <- read.table(text = "College Names Food rating Critic Rating Student rating

John Hopkins Institute 8.4 8.6 9.2

Stanford : New School 9.4 5.6 9.2

Mayor College 6.4 7.6 4.2",  
                header = TRUE, quote="", sep="\t")
```

Extract data into relevant columns:

```
library(tidyr)    
df %>%
  extract(College.Names.Food.rating.Critic.Rating.Student.rating,
          into = c("College_Name", "Food_rating", "Critic_Rating", "Student_Rating"),
          regex = "(\\D+)\\s(\\d\\.\\d)\\s(\\d\\.\\d)\\s(\\d\\.\\d)")
            College_Name Food_rating Critic_Rating Student_Rating
1 John Hopkins Institute         8.4           8.6            9.2
2  Stanford : New School         9.4           5.6            9.2
3          Mayor College         6.4           7.6            4.2
```